# Get full path of images in a subfolder in python + flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am trying to build a simple gallery using python and Flask but I got stuck getting the path of the images IF the images are in a subfolder under the main folder static.

The folder structure I got is: 'static' >> 'images'

The following code is working IF the images are un the root of the folder 'static'.

app.py

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    image_names = os.listdir('./static/')
    # print(image_names)
    return render_template('index.html', image_names=image_names)
```

index.html

```
{% for image_name in image_names %}
    <img src=" {{url_for('static', filename=image_name)}}"> {% endfor %}
```

But I can not figure out how I can add 'images' in the path of the url

```
{{url_for('static', filename=image_name)}}">
```

I have tried many different ways, watched tutorials, read the docs but I just got errors...

*> I am learning Python and Flask so, please don't be mean in your comments...*

Answer (score 0):

use `{{ url_for('static', filename='folder_name/file_name') }}`

hope that will help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that way doesn't work. In my code "image_name" is a variable that retunrs the name of the image. In the way you said just retunr:
"/static/images/image_name".

Thanks

Comment: <img src=" {{url_for('static', filename='images/image_name')}}">

Comment: can you try <img src=" {{ url_for('static', filename='images/image_name.image_extension') }}">

Comment: It doesn´t work either :( This is the output in the HTML
"/static/images/image_name.image_extension" isntead of the name of the image

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please add an explanation, indicating how or why this suggestiin solves  the OP's issue. This will increase long term value and quality of your contribution, help future visitors apply that knowledge to their own code, and increase likeliness of receiving upvotes. Code only answers are generally frowned upon in SO. Explanations increase rapid understanding, and sharing of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
@app.route('/static/images/<filename>')
def get_images_route(filename):
    return './static/images/' + filename
```

in HTML

```
<img src=" {{url_for('get_images_route', filename=image_name)}}">
```